# How to edit MediaWiki HTML Header?

Tags: html, header, mediawiki, wiki, wikimedia

My goal is to edit the HTML header of my wiki articles. I want to add some `hreflang` tags, depending on the availability of that particular article in a certain language.

Basically i have got two questions: How do i get the languages before the page is loaded & how do i get the `hreflang` tags of these languages into the header?

I have done some searching, but did not find anything on the topic. Is it even possible, to edit the html headers?

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For addings link tags (eg `<link hreflang>`) you should use [OutputPage::addLink](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classOutputPage.html#a0a5a13c217ca4eed7a88945bd63ec730). There is also a generic [OutputPage::addHeadItem](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classOutputPage.html#ad37dc926166096712154a6e2e3ca33d8) function. In other words, you will do something like this (depending on if you are doing this from an extension, from a skin, or something else):

```
global $wgOut;
$wgOut->addLink( 'hreflang' => 'fa' );
```

to create a tag like `<link hreflang="fa">` in the page header.

Comment: I could not make it work yet. I have got a custom skin. Where am i supposed to add the code exactly? It dod not work In my custom-skin php file.

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of you code! That way people can help you find what's going wrong.